# Consulta em sql para Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Esse é o exemplo da consulta `sql`, estou tentando fazer essa mesma consulta em `Laravel` se puder ajudar agradeço.

> `SELECT p.nome,(select min(op.preco_unitario) from opcao_produto op
>   where p.id = op.produto_id) preco from produto p WHERE (select
>   min(op.preco_unitario) from opcao_produto op where p.id =
>   op.produto_id) BETWEEN 202 and 1000`

Comment: se está fazendo com `Eloquent`?

Answer (score 0):

Tentei converter essa mesma query usando principalmente a função **[raw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions)**.

**é claro que isto pode ser muito mais otimizado!**

O Resultado foi este **(não testei)**:

```
DB::select(
        DB::raw('p.nome'),
        DB::raw('(select min(op.preco_unitario) from opcao_produto op where p.id = op.produto_id)'),
        'preco'
    )->from(DB::raw('produto p'))
    ->whereRaw('(select min(op.preco_unitario) from opcao_produto op where p.id = op.produto_id)')
    ->whereBetween('COLUNA', [202, 1000])->get();
```

Comment: Bem testei a consulta é deu esse erro                                 
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, object given.